# Flutter - convert HTML to delta (quill)

Tags: flutter, dart, parsing, package, quill

how it is possible in dart to parse html to delta ?

I only found package to convert quill to HTML but it seems not possible to do that from the other side.

Maybe someone has already solved this issue.

I have already tried several packages.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a popular question for the Quill package. However, the author does not have a plan for this feature, so you can try to write it.

You can try using the regex logic combined with **flutter_html** package

Note: HTML is a hypertext markup language, so you can't cover all cases for converting HTML to delta

UPDATE: [This package](https://github.com/fleather-editor/fleather/tree/master/packages/parchment) can support you to convert, however, I don't use this yet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all paste this code in the file and then call it in init state to get data in quillController in delta format.

```
class HtmlToDeltaConverter {

 static const _COLOR_PATTERN = r'color: rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\);';

 static Delta _parseInlineStyles(htmlDom.Element element) {
var delta = Delta();

for (final node in element.nodes) {
  final attributes = _parseElementStyles(element);

  if (element.localName == 'h1') {
    // Special handling for <h1>
    delta..insert(element.text, {'header': 1})..insert('\n', {}); // Correctly apply block-level attribute
  } else {
    // Handle other elements (inline styles, images, etc.)
    for (final node in element.nodes) {
      if (node is htmlDom.Text) {
        delta.insert(node.text, attributes);
      } else if (node is htmlDom.Element && node.localName == 'br') {
        delta.insert('\n');
      } else if (node is htmlDom.Element && node.localName == 'img') {
        final src = node.attributes['src'];
        if (src != null) {
          delta.insert({'image': src});
        }
      } else if (node is htmlDom.Element) {
        // Recursive call for nested elements
        delta = delta.concat(_parseInlineStyles(node));
      }
    }
  }

return delta;

}
return delta;
}

static Delta _parseInline2Styles(htmlDom.Element element,) {
var delta = Delta();

for (final node in element.nodes) {
  final attributes = _parseElementStyles(element);

  if (element.localName == 'h1') {
    // Insert the text content of the <h1> element
    delta.insert(element.text);
    // Properly end the block with a newline and apply the header attribute
    delta.insert('\n', {'header': 1});
  }else if(element.localName == 'h2'){
    // Insert the text content of the <h1> element
    delta.insert(element.text);
    // Properly end the block with a newline and apply the header attribute
    delta.insert('\n', {'header': 2});
  } else if(element.localName == 'h3'){
    // Insert the text content of the <h1> element
    delta.insert(element.text);
    // Properly end the block with a newline and apply the header attribute
    delta.insert('\n', {'header': 3});
  }  else if(node is htmlDom.Element){
    delta = delta.concat(_parseInlineStyles(node));
  }
}

return delta;
}
static Delta _parseInline3Styles(htmlDom.Element element,) {
var delta = Delta();

for (final node in element.nodes) {
  // final attributes = _parseElementStyles(element);

  if (node is htmlDom.Element && node.localName == 'li') {
    final attributes = _parseListElementStyles(node);
    delta.insert(node.text);
    delta.insert('\n', attributes);
  } else if(node is htmlDom.Element){
    delta = delta.concat(_parseInlineStyles(node));
  }

}

return delta;
}

static Delta _parseInline4Styles(htmlDom.Element element,) {
var delta = Delta();

for (final node in element.nodes) {
  // final attributes = _parseElementStyles(element);

  if (node is htmlDom.Element && node.localName == 'li') {
    delta = delta.concat(_parseListItem(node));
  }

}

return delta;
}

static Map<String, dynamic> _parseListElementStyles(htmlDom.Element element) {
final Map<String, dynamic> attributes = {};

// Existing style parsing logic...

// Check for list tags and apply list attributes
if (element.localName == 'li') {
  final parent = element.parent;
  if (parent != null && parent.localName == 'ul') {
    attributes['list'] = 'bullet';
  } else if (parent != null && parent.localName == 'ol') {
    attributes['list'] = 'ordered';
  } 
  var checkbox = element.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
  if (checkbox != null) {
      // If a checkbox is found, determine if it's checked
      bool isChecked = checkbox.attributes.containsKey('checked');
      attributes['checked'] = isChecked; // Add 'checked' attribute to the list item
  }
}

return attributes;
}

static Delta _parseListItem(htmlDom.Element element) {
var delta = Delta();
bool isChecked = false;

// Check if the list item contains an input element of type checkbox
var inputElement = element.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
if (inputElement != null) {
  isChecked = inputElement.attributes.containsKey('checked');
}

// Now handle the text of the list item, assuming it follows the input checkbox
var textContent = element.text.trim(); // .trim() to remove leading/trailing whitespaces
// The attributes map could include other styling attributes as well, if needed
var attributes = <String, dynamic>{};
if (isChecked) {
  attributes['checked'] = true; // Custom attribute to represent checked state
}
// Assuming list items are always part of an unordered list in this example
attributes['list'] = 'bullet';

delta..insert(textContent)..insert('\n', attributes);

return delta;
}

static Map<String, dynamic> _parseElementStyles(htmlDom.Element element) {
final Map<String, dynamic> attributes = {};

if (element.localName == 'strong') attributes['bold'] = true;
if (element.localName == 'em') attributes['italic'] = true;
if (element.localName == 'u') attributes['underline'] = true;
if (element.localName == 'del') attributes['strike'] = true;
if(element.localName == 'header') attributes['header'] = true;

final style = element.attributes['style'];
if (style != null) {
  final colorValue = _parseColorFromStyle(style);
  if (colorValue != null) attributes['color'] = colorValue;

  final bgColorValue = _parseBackgroundColorFromStyle(style);
  if (bgColorValue != null) attributes['background'] = bgColorValue;
}

return attributes;
}

static String? _parseColorFromStyle(String style) {
if (RegExp(r'(^|\s)color:(\s|$)').hasMatch(style)) {
  return _parseRgbColorFromMatch(RegExp(_COLOR_PATTERN).firstMatch(style));
}
return null;
}

static String? _parseBackgroundColorFromStyle(String style) {
if (RegExp(r'(^|\s)background-color:(\s|$)').hasMatch(style)) {
  return _parseRgbColorFromMatch(RegExp(_COLOR_PATTERN).firstMatch(style));
}
return null;
}

static String? _parseRgbColorFromMatch(RegExpMatch? colorMatch) {
if (colorMatch != null) {
  try {
    final red = int.parse(colorMatch.group(1)!);
    final green = int.parse(colorMatch.group(2)!);
    final blue = int.parse(colorMatch.group(3)!);
    return '#${red.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}${green.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}${blue.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}';
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrintStack(label: e.toString());
  }
}
return null;
}
static Delta htmlToDelta(String html) {
final document = htmlparse.parse(html);
var delta = Delta();

for (final node in document.body?.nodes ?? []) {
  if (node is htmlDom.Element) {
    switch (node.localName) {
      case 'p':
        delta = delta.concat(_parseInlineStyles(node))..insert('\n');
        break;
      case 'br':
        delta.insert('\n');
        break;
      case 'h1':
        delta = delta.concat(_parseInline2Styles(node));
        // delta.insert('\n');
        break;
      case 'h2':
        delta = delta.concat(_parseInline2Styles(node));
        // delta.insert('\n');
        break;
      case 'h3':
        delta = delta.concat(_parseInline2Styles(node));
        break;
      case 'ol':
        delta = delta.concat(_parseInline3Styles(node));
        break;
      case 'ul':
        delta = delta.concat(_parseInline3Styles(node));
        break;
    }
  }
  }

  return html.isNotEmpty ? delta : Delta()..insert('\n');
}
}
```

Now to convert data in to delta and initialize it

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
var delta = HtmlToDeltaConverter.htmlToDelta(htmlString);


quillController = QuillController(
  document: Document.fromDelta(delta),
  selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
);
}
```